# Why x86 debug registers DR4 and DR5 are not used?

Tags: debugging, intel, x86

As per Intel manual- System programming guide Vol3A, Chapter 16 -

> Debug registers DR4 and DR5 are reserved when debug extensions are
>   enabled (when the DE flag in control register CR4 is set) and attempts
>   to reference the DR4 and DR5 registers cause invalid-opcode exceptions
>   (#UD). When debug extensions are not enabled (when the DE flag is
>   clear), these registers are aliased to debug registers DR6 and DR7

.

DR4 & DR5 are reserved when DE flag in CR4 is set. And they are aliased to DR6 & DR7 when DE flag is not set. Then what is use of DR4 & DR5? I dont see usage of DR4 & DR5 in either case.

Did they had usage in older x88 arch ?